# upload file greater than 10MB

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback

I am trying to upload a file>10MB in a web project
and i get this error
maxFileSize exceeded, 10551296 bytes of zone data received (max is 10485760)

so how can I upload a file greater than 10MB?
help me please

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please consider adding a MCVE (see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question.

Answer (score 1):

The maxFileSize parameter is configured in the datasources.json file:

```
"storage": {
    "name": "storage",
    "connector": "loopback-component-storage",
    "allowedContentTypes": ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png"],
    "provider": "filesystem",
    "maxFileSize":  "1048576",
    "root": "image"
  }
}
```